# Multiple-value in single-value context ERROR

Tags: go

I got this error while compiling my GO code:

```
multiple-value fmt.Println() in single-value context
```

I'm trying to create a function that takes in variable number of ints and prints each variable on a line.

GO:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int{1,3,4,5}
    vf(slice...)
}

func vf(a ...int) int {
    if len(a)==0 {
        return 0
    }
    var x int
    for _, v := range a {
        x = fmt.Println(v)
    }
    return x
}
```

Hmm what's wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to assign the output of `fmt.Println`? Did you mean to use `fmt.Sprintln`?

Comment: the values in the slice so that it can be printed out

Comment: Println prints to stdout, if you read the documentation it shows that the return values are `(int, error)`, not the output.

Comment: duplicate of [Go Error: "multiple-value filepath.Glob() in single-value context"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741665/go-error-multiple-value-filepath-glob-in-single-value-context)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out http://godoc.org/fmt#Println

`fmt.Println` returns multiple values.. an int and and error:

`func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)`

You are only assigning to the int.  try this:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []int{1,3,4,5}
    vf(slice...)
}

func vf(a ...int) int {
    if len(a)==0 {
        return 0
    }
    var x int
    for _, v := range a {
        x, _ = fmt.Println(v)
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: I'm 90% sure he's trying to use `fmt.Sprintf not `Println`.

Comment: that may be the case, but i'm not so sure based on his original question:

`I'm trying to create a function that takes in variable number of ints and prints each variable on a line.`

He wants to `print` each variable on a line. This implies Println. The odd this about the function is that he wants to return the number of characters written for the last number. Seems like he doesn't need a return value whatsoever based on the original question, but his issue was with the syntax of the `fmt.Println` function, so I addressed that, not his algorithm.